# sql error when submitting with php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

My php files that submits an entry to a database table isn't working and I can't figure out why. It takes in an Ajax submit and I know that the problem isn't with the data, or the Ajax request as it processes as a success. The only issue is that no data is ever submitted to my database. I had this working before I changed to code to concatenate the address string where it was one variable before. Any advice would be great!

Here is the php files
UPDATE:::THIS IS THE UPDATED PHP FILE

```
 <?php
require("dbinfo.php");

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$name = $_POST['user_name'];
$street = $_POST['user_street'];
$city = $_POST['user_city'];
$state = $_POST['user_state'];
$country = $_POST['user_country'];
$zip = $_POST['user_zip'];

$address = $street.', '.$city.', '.$state.', '.$country.', '.$zip;
$shortAdd = $city.', '.$state.', '.$country;

$type = $_POST['user_color'];
$desc = $_POST['user_message'];
$request_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$address."&sensor=true";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");
$status = $xml->status;
if ($status=="OK") {
      $lat = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
      $lon = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng;
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`, `type`, `desc`) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $name, $shortAdd, $lat, $lon, $type, $desc);
$stmt->execute();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Can you show us the error if any?

Comment: no error? it goes through and the form submits when the button is clicked but the mySQL database doesn't have a new table after.

Comment: Did you execute your SQL statement? I noticed that there's no commit or $sql->query()

Comment: the query is never run. your open to SQL injection attacck

Comment: How do I execute the SQL statement?

Comment: ". I had this working before " you probably just removed the code to do it, so put it back in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While docliving's answer is correct, ***please*** take the extra step and use prepared statements. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks without it. It just takes a very minor change to convert it to use prepared statements. Here is how to do it with mysqli:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`, `type`, `desc`) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $name, $shortAdd, $lat, $lon, $type, $desc);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: @CollinMcCabe I think you have another problem if it's not working with docliving's code. Mine should work the same way.

Comment: For reference the site is globalcandlelight.com and the form shows up when you click on a candle. It seems to work but no new marker comes up afterwards. The markers which pull from the database are working however

Comment: @CollinMcCabe If you have Chrome, you can click anywhere on your page and click on "Inspect". Then click the "Network" tab, and try submitting the ajax request. You should see a new request in the network tab. Click on it and check the response tab and make sure there are no php or mysql errors.

Comment: with the safari dev tools it doesn't seem to show any error, it outputs this in network:        www.globalcandlelight.com       resource-type-xhr POST HTTP         200  530    803  0.24327645999437664 23.741015441002673

Comment: @CollinMcCabe It will always show a HTTP 200 if it successfully connected to your server but that doesn't mean there are no php errors. Click on that line and see if you can see the output from your php script.

Comment: FIXED!!!!!! it was your fix and one other small thing somewhere else. Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

When @MySelfBoy wrote:

> After the assignment, you have to execute SQL statements

He means that you have to execute your query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`, `type`, `desc`) 
    VALUES ('$name', '$shortAdd', '$lat', '$lon', '$type', '$desc');";
```

with the following instruction:

```
$conn->query($sql);
```

NOTE: I Still can´t make comments, so I'm posting it here.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be working after I added that in